# SWI-Prolog and filename extensions: Why won't swipl recognize a file with an extension?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using SWI-Prolog's command-line interpreter swipl. I run it inside a directory containing a file `test.pro`, and try to call

`[test.pro].`

This causes swipl to spew

`ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: [test
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: .pro] .`

However, if I remove the extension, it works just fine. Is there any way to pass filenames to swipl to load which have extension that won't cause this error? In fact, I'd like to know *what* is causing this error, because SWI-Prolog's website is not very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument of `[]` is an atom. An atom that contains a dot must be surrounded by `'`:

```
['test.pro'].
```

Answer (score 5):

to complete Magus' answer, note that SWI-Prolog let you declare the valid extensions for Prolog source files: add to your ~/.plrc (or the windows counterpart) the declaration

```
user:prolog_file_type(pro, prolog).
```

and then you will get the file with

```
?- [test].
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though it now appears the file name of the config is  `.swiplrc`. For those interested **gprolog** seems to support `.pro` out of the box aside from `.pl`, though not `.prolog`.

Comment: For more recent versions, both the filename and the directory may be different. For 8.1 and later, [the filename is `init.pl`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PlInitialisation.html). [Get the directory name](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=initfile) by using the call `absolute_file_name(app_config(.), Dir, [file_type(directory)]).`

Answer (score 0):

SWI prolog's convention is to use a '.pl' extension, so if you use that instead, things will run a lot smoother, and you won't have to worry about your dots.

Then you can just consult with:

```
[test].
```

.. and it will assume a .pl extension, and look for test.pl in your folder.